# Simulate the "next" button behavior of iOS using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ios, ipad

Is it possible to simulate the "next" button behavior (auto-focus the next field) of iOS using JavaScript?

When I trigger the focus of the next element the keyboard doesn't show up. Here's a simple [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jvqkS/).